# How to get node data from comment email notification with hook_mail_alter

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-9

I'm using the comment_notify module. Looking to change a part of the email sent out when a comment is made with a custom module using the hook_mail_alter() - Problem is as far as I can tell, I can't access the node data directly with this method as its not passed on the form and I can't pass on the Entity or Form Interface as a second parameter as the function does not allow a second paramter.

I have been able to extract the comment Id in hopes of finding the node by using the id of the comment attached to it with no luck.